# BouncyCastleProvider do not get PrivateKey and certificate chain from PKCS#12 file

Tags: java, bouncycastle, private-key, pkcs#12, pfx

I have file `cert.pfx` exported on Windows. This file contains my certificate. On Ubuntu i can open it with password and I see the certificate. But when I loaded this file:

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
KeyStore ks = ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/home/test/.cert.pfx", "xxxxxx".toCharArray());
String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pts.getRandom());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

After this operations I have `null` in `pk` and `chain`.
Also I have registered BC provider in `java.security`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `BouncyCastleProvider` to `SunJSSE`. Now my correctly code is:

```
String providerName = "SunJSSE";
KeyStore ks = ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", providerName);
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/home/test/.cert.pfx", "xxxxxx".toCharArray());
String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pts.getRandom());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

Now in `pk` is my privarte key, and in `chain` is certificate chain.
I don't know why in BC doesn't work. I have other certificate and BC provider work correctly.